# Internet Sharing on Mac OS X with Websites Control

Tags: macos, internet, website, blocking

I am successfully sharing my Internet from my Macbook with others but I wonder is there a way I can block facebook.com or other sites for my users keeping my access to them?

Comment: I guess a way would be to install [Squid proxy](http://web.me.com/adg/squidman/index.html) and then [block Facebook](http://msoos.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/block-facebook-using-squid-at-office/). Can't try it out right now but the only problem would be discerning between local access and access over the shared connection.

Comment: yes you're right but is there a guide of Squid for MAC?

Comment: Squid on OS X is not that different from the *nix versions I guess. Haven't looked into it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is! Check out [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) or just adjust local parental controls. OpenDNS will prevent your users from resolving the DNS for facebook.com. The only problem is you'll need to change their DNS servers yourself.

Alternatively, you can change it on your connection and then use your OpenDNS username and password to get through.